# i cant find my tables in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-express

I am using `visual studio 2015` and creating a MVC project. I wanted to create a local Database with `sql express`.

I clicked the `App_Data` folder and choose `Add New Item` and then I selected SQL Server Database. Then I clicked the Tables Folder and choosing Add New Table. After that I create my table and I want to save my table I will direct to the window with this Title `Save changes to the following items?`

`dbo.Tables.sql*.` and when I click Yes it will open the save window and then I saved my file and come back to server explorer I don't have any table in Tables folder.i don't know how I can have my tables here????

Comment: You can put a breakpoint just before saving the record, stop there and look at the connection string your context is pointing to. It sometimes gets tricky with local db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save your table, it is really just saving the server scripts. Instead you need to hit the update button to run the scripts and create the tables in your Db and you can find your tables by going to View > SQL Server Object Explorer.

Comment: Yes. That s it! Thanks a lot:)